# how to migrate virtual machine scale set in windows azure (asp.net)

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I'm working on web app and i want to migrate this web app to virtual machine scale set in windows azure cloud,i'm new to cloud computing ,till i didn't got any proper tutorial about virtual machine scale set,please someone help with this

Answer (score 1):

A few things to consider..

1. You could build a custom VM which contains the complete app, or you could use VM extensions to deploy the app on a platform image each time a new VM in the scale set is deployed. See: https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/04/20/deploying-applications-in-azure-vm-scale-sets/ for some thoughts on this. Ultimately it might depend on how much you need to install over a base image, and how fast you want scaling to be.
2. Do you need autoscale based on resource usage or do you plan to manually increase/decrease the number of VMs in the set? See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machine-scale-sets-windows-autoscale/
3. A good way to get started with scale sets is to deploy an existing template directly from Azure Quick start templates. Look at https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates and search for vmss. These templates will give you an idea of some of the options you have.
4. To learn the basics about VM Scale Sets, start with the documentation page: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/services/virtual-machine-scale-sets/ and the GA announcement: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-virtual-machine-scale-sets-ga/
5. Also look at higher level services like the Azure Web App service if you haven't already, the advantage of a higher level service is that some of the basic web app operations get taken care of for you: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/